# Moving internal ubuntu install to external and booting from it

Tags: ubuntu

I want to move an existing internal Ubuntu installation to an external drive.

I've put what was my internal HDD into and external case and set my bios to recognise booting from USB.  The result is I just get a blank screen from the start.

I've tested the booting from USB with a seperate Ubuntu installation USB and it recognises it and allows me to test or install as it should.

I'm guessing I need to change the boot folder on the now external drive, but the searching I've done I can't find how to do it?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's  not about programming. Try http://askubuntu.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you burn [Boot repair disc](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) on another computer and use it to install boot loader to external drive